# pass constant list (immutable) in variadic in Go

Tags: go

```
var state = [...]string{
    "new",
    "submitted",
    "approved",
    "rejected",
}

In(values ...interface{}) {
  return
}
```

I need to pass an immutable list to a variadic function in go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a slice or array of strings to a function that accepts a variadic argument list of `interface{}` types. You have to first create an `[]interface{}`, and pass that:

```
args:=make([]interface{},len(state))
for i,x:=range state {
   args[i]=x
}
In(args...)
```

Comment: By the way, `state` is not a slice, but rather an array (has the type `[4]string`).